# Endomorphism ring isomorphic to regular representation

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Given the regular representation, $\rho : G \rightarrow GL(K[G])$ define $End_{G}(K[G]) = \{ \phi : K[G] \rightarrow K[G] \text{ s.t. } \rho_{g} \circ \phi = \phi \circ \rho_{g} , \forall g \in G \}$. I want to show that $End_{G}(K[G]) \cong K[G]$. To do so, I observed that $\phi$ is determined by $\phi(1)$ because $\phi(\sum_{g \in G} a_{g} g) = \sum_{g \in G} a_{g} g \cdot \phi(1)$. I was trying to construct an isomorphism $\psi : End_{G}(K[G]) \rightarrow K[G]$ by $\psi(\phi) = \phi(1)$. This is a bijective map, but it is not an isomorphism. Suppose that $\phi_{1}(1) = \sum_{g \in G} a_{g} g$ and $\phi_{2}(1) = \sum_{b \in G} b_{g} g$. Then $\psi(\phi_{1} \phi_{2}) = \phi_{1} \circ \phi_{2} (1) = \phi_{1}(1) \cdot \phi_{2}(1)$, but I am not sure this is true because: 
$$\phi_{1}(1) \cdot \phi_{2}(1) = \sum_{g_{1}, g_{2} \in G} a_{g_{1}} b_{g_{2}} g_{1} g_{2}$$. 
But 
$$\phi_{1} \circ \phi_{2}(1) = \sum_{g_{1} , g_{2} \in G} b_{g_{1}} a_{g_{2}} g_{1} g_{2}$$.

Are these quantities actually equal? I don't think so.